# React-Native : Voice Over (iOS) to read the new element

Tags: ios, react-native, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am new to react-native and from frontend background development and UX.

We are using react-native for building an application, everything was fine until we really started focusing on VoiceOver and TalkBack.

The problem is whenever new elements get rendered on the view (for instance list view or view or error message), the VoiceOver doesn't read the message and while using Bluetooth keyboard, it never selects/navigates to the newly added element.

I am not sure how to use or integrate iOS native UIAccessibilityPostNotification. Please read this for more info. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/voiceover-accessibility/

Need help on this if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> VoiceOver doesn't read the message and while using Bluetooth keyboard
>   The state of accessibility for React-Native changed a lot in the last two years.

```
<MyView accessible={true} accessibilityLabel="My label for VoiceOver or TalkBack">My label</MyView>
```

Will make TalkBack and Voice over read this element when the focus reaches it.

references:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/08/13/react-native-accessibility-updates
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibilityinfo