# Accessibility in React Native Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, jsx, native

Is it possible to use accessibility props in combination with React Navigation core components, like NavigationContainer? I'm making a mobile app with a navbar and I need to create a mechanism that will force TalkBack/VoiceOver to read navigator first.

Comment: Is this helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55486484/3825777 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/54176688/3825777 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/63919849/3825777